# How to get information on mobile through bluetooth, send information by my notebook

Tags: delphi, java-me, bluetooth, communication, delphi-xe2

I want mobile phones to communicate with the my notebook. I am using Delphi for Windows programming and component nrComm Lib that methods for sending and receiving Char, String there.

```
  nrBT1.SendString();
  nrBT1.SendString();
  nrBT1.SendData();
```

But my problem is on the phone how can I get information.I'm not a professional Java programming.I have read the article but will not do it with component nrComm Lib:(

[jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client.](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client/)
I think the following code can not be implemented in Delphi:

```
//Create a UUID for SPP
UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", true);
//Create the servicve url
String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid +";name=Sample SPP Server";
```

Comment: My main goal is to control the device via Bluetooth.

Comment: if you want to do this "pain-free", stick with Java, there are quite a few demos out there